# Linux Machine time mismatch with all other logs time

Tags: linux, logs, date, tomcat

I have deployed multiple wars on QA environment but when I am doing date command on my Linux machine, it is showing Correct PST time that I have set but in the logs I am getting different time. Same WAR is being deployed on dev environment as well which is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

The timezone setting of your session is not necessarily the same as the system default timezone. If you set the TZ environment variable fo your session, make sure you set it in your application start-up script too, so that it will be set both when you start the application manually and when (or if) the system auto-starts the application at boot.

System logs are usually output in the system default timezone; application logs can be output in whatever timezone was specified in the TZ environment variable when the application was started up. If the TZ variable is unset, then system default timezone is used.

Use `date -u` to verify that the system has the correct UTC time information.
If the UTC value is wrong, but the local time value seems correct, something is wrong with the timezone settings.

The system default timezone is determined by copying the appropriate timezone file from the `/usr/share/zoneinfo` directory to `/etc/localtime`.

In RedHat and related distributions, there is also `/etc/sysconfig/clock` that includes the default timezone specification - but that won't actually **set** the default timezone: instead, it just **informs** which timezone file has been placed into `/etc/localtime` by the OS installer. Changing the timezone specified in `/etc/sysconfig/clock` alone won't actually change the system default timezone: you must also update the `/etc/localtime` file to match. This has tripped up several new sysadmins.